# how to include google analytics in each page but eccomerce tracking only in my 'thank you page'

Tags: google-analytics

I've included the Google Analytics tracking in the layout of my site so each page can be tracked.

```
<script> 
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-YY', 'none');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
   </script>
```

And I want to include  the script for ecommerce tracking only in my last thank you page after a purchase has been made.

```
             <script> 

                 ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                'id': '<%:order.DocumentNo%>',                   // Transaction ID. Required.
                'revenue': '<%:order.TotalOrderPriceWithVat%>',  // Grand Total.
                'shipping': '<%:order.TotalTransportPrice %>',   // Shipping.
                'tax': '0'                                       // Tax.
            });

    <
            ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
                'id':   '<%:order.DocumentNo %>',                 // Transaction ID. Required.
                'name': '<%:item.ProductDescription %>' +' '+ '<%:item.BrandName%>',  // Product name. Required.
                'sku': '<%:item.Item_Id %>',                    //Item ID

                'category': '<%:item.CustomData %>',                          // Category or variation.
                'price': '<%:item.OrderPriceWithVat %>',       // Unit price.
                'quantity': '<%:item.Quantity %>'            // Quantity.
            });





</script>
```

The problem is in the last page I get the error **ga is undefined**

Comment: How  are you injecting the GA code onto each page? On the TY page, do you see the GA snippet when you view source? If it says GA is undefined that means it's not being loaded before the ecomm code

Answer (score 2):

### Basic tracking

1. load analytics.js library
2. init tracker (create)
3. track pageview

   ```
   <script> 
       (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
           i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
               (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
           }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
           m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
       })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-YYY', 'none');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
   ```

### Ecommerce tracking

1. load analytics.js library
2. init tracker (create)
3. load ecommerce plugin
4. track pageview
5. add transaction description
6. track transaction

   ```
   <script> 
       (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
           i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
               (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
           }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
           m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
       })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-YYY', 'none');
       ga('require', 'ecommerce'); // load ecommerce plugin
       ga('send', 'pageview');

       ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
           'id': '<%:order.DocumentNo%>',                   // Transaction ID. Required.
           'revenue': '<%:order.TotalOrderPriceWithVat%>',  // Grand Total.
           'shipping': '<%:order.TotalTransportPrice %>',   // Shipping.
           'tax': '0'                                       // Tax.
       });


       ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
           'id':   '<%:order.DocumentNo %>',                 // Transaction ID. Required.
           'name': '<%:item.ProductDescription %>' +' '+ '<%:item.BrandName%>',  // Product name. Required.
           'sku': '<%:item.Item_Id %>',                    //Item ID

           'category': '<%:item.CustomData %>',                          // Category or variation.
           'price': '<%:item.OrderPriceWithVat %>',       // Unit price.
           'quantity': <%:item.Quantity %>            // Quantity.
       });

       ga('ecommerce:send'); // track transaction
   ```

### Documentation

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: I updated the post, there were quotes at the quantity parameter, but it is INTeger!